# How to download "actual" data from iPhone Health App?

Tags: ios, iphone, export, apple-watch, healthkit

There are iPhone XR and Apple Watch 2. My aim is to download my latest BMP data from Health App.
But, I cannot download actual data. IOS is giving all the time obsolete data. However, I can see in Health Apps Show All Data actual BPMs.

How can I export all(minutes ago heart rate) data atom Health App

I will be gratefull for any help.

With best regards,

Comment: show your code.

Comment: there is no code. Usually, one can download his/her health data from Health  App in IOS. The deal is iOS is not allowing download up-to-date data immediately. It returns me obsolete data

Comment: I see. Where are you dropping the export file?

Comment: I wanted to download my health data from iPhone into MacBook. I did it. But data in export file is obsolete.

Comment: tell me in detail where you put the export file. You cannot export from the phone directly to your MacBook.